# Secure delete file

Tags: file, security

Would it be called a `secure delete` when for example you convert a certain file a "video" to text file and edit it like removing all data/text then save and delete?

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking, but it's definitely not a secure delete.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by converting video to text file, but anyway here goes.

This would depend on other factors such as the OS, whether it's BIOS/UEFI and even what type of Drive is being used, but it is safe to say that in most situations you **definitely** need to do more than just convert the file and change the internals.

What happens on the OS layer does not represent what happens on the lower layers and the gap is becoming wider with new technologies such as SSD.